# What is the conditional probability $P(X \gt 0 \mid X + Y \gt 0)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are both independent standard normal random variables,

with $X \sim  {\rm N} (0; 1)$ and $Y \sim  {\rm N} (0; 1)$.

Comment: Three-fourths. Now please explain your approach.

Comment: Here is my approach, what wrong did I do? for X+Y to be greater than 0; one of this conditions should hold, 1) X>0 and Y>0 or 2) X<0 and Y>0 but Y>X or 3) X>0 and Y<0 but X>Y First event has a probability of 1/4. second and third events have same probability by symmetry. so, 1/4+2k=1 ; say k is the probability of second and third events. which gives k =3/8 so, the probability of X>0 should be 1/4+3/8 = 5/8

Comment: My assumption here is, as it is given X+Y is greater than 0, one of those three conditions must hold all the time in the conditional universe of X+Y>0, which implies the probability of those three conditions must sum up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want 
$$\frac{\Pr((X\gt 0) \cap (X+Y\gt 0))}{\Pr(X+Y\gt 0)}.$$
By symmetry the denominator is $\frac{1}{2}$.

For the numerator, we want the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of the plane that is to the right of the $y$-axis, and above the line $y=-x$. By symmetry this is $\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: I wanted to ask your advice - you have been around much more than me :-). On questions like this, how do you determine when to post answers (like yours, pretty much doing it for the OP), when to post hints, and when to just comment asking the OP to state his own thoughts in order not to do the hw for him?

Comment: I am stricter when there is a homework label (and I notice it!). And there are other factors, I find geometric language appealing, and figured that deciphering "by symmetry" might lead to useful learning. Of course it will be totally useless if it is indeed a homework assignment and OP merely copies the *word*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood what you did. Can you please point out the mistake in my approach?

Comment: For example, the *conditional* probability that $X$ and $Y$ are both positive, *given* that $X+Y\gt 0$, is not equal to the unconditional probability that $X$ and $Y$ are both positive. That unconditional probability is indeed $\frac{1}{4}$, but we are calculating a conditional probability.